# How to fix Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\FilesController::uploadAttachments()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, project-management

I am developing project management tool in laravel 5.2. In my application user can create a project and one project has many tasks and one task may have many files attachments. I am using cloudder to save My files. Currently I have assigned My project files to relevant projects only. Now, I need to display the files on each tasks of the relevant projects.

FileController

```
class FilesController extends Controller
    {

        public function uploadAttachments(Request $request, $id,$taskId) //this is line 20
        {
             $this->validate($request, [
                'file_name'     => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,pdf|between:1,7000',
            ]);

            $filename     = $request->file('file_name')->getRealPath();

            Cloudder::upload($filename, null);
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

            $fileUrl = Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId(), ["width" => $width, "height" => $height]);
            $this->saveUploads($request, $fileUrl, $id,$taskId);

            return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Your Attachment has been uploaded Successfully');
        }

        private function saveUploads(Request $request, $fileUrl, $id,$taskId)
        {
            $file = new File;
            $file->file_name  = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->file_url   = $fileUrl;
            $file->project_id = $id;
            $file->task_id = $taskId;

            $file->save();
        }

        return redirect()->route('projects.show')->with('info', 'File deleted successfully');
        }
    }
```

routes

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/files', [
     'uses' => 'FilesController@uploadAttachments',
     'as'   => 'projects.files',
     'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

and file form is files/form.blade.php

```
 <div class="row" style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin-left:5px;width:100%;padding:15px;">
     @foreach($project->files as $file)
                <div>
                    <div><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                        <span>

                            <a href="{{ $file->file_url }}" target="_blank">{{ $file->file_name }}</a>
                  </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                @endforeach

        <form class="form-vertical" role="form"
                                    enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                    method="post"
                                    action="{{ route('projects.files', ['projectId'=> $project->id, 'taskId'=>$task->id])}}">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('file_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="file" name="file_name" class="form-control" id="file_name">
                @if ($errors->has('file_name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('file_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Files</button>
            </div>
```

Now I got this error:

> ErrorException in FilesController.php line 20: Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\FilesController::uploadAttachments()

How can I fix this?

Comment: I need some help here.....

Comment: no any ideas to solve this problem???...

Comment: do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try `Route::post('projects/{id}/files`

Comment: actually this is about taskId problem

Comment: Ah sorry yes (im a bit ill), well your not passing in a 3rd argument through the route. Though my laravel is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the required parameters in your route declaration.
Add **`projectId`** and **`taskId`**.

```
Route::post('projects/{projectId}/files/{taskId}', [
     'uses' => 'FilesController@uploadAttachments',
     'as'   => 'projects.files',
     'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

And mention them in controller method correctly.

```
public function uploadAttachments(Request $request, $projectId, $taskId)
{
    // 
}
```

Comment: can You gess My form action regarding with your route and controller. My form.blade.php file is in the answer...

Comment: The full url in you form action (after my route declaration) will become /projects/1/files/2 (say projectId = 1 and taskId =2)
 (**/projects/projectId/files/taskId**).